# Can an employer dictate when an employee can take annual leave?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

My employer is trying enforce new rules about how we use our annual leave. Among other points they require the following are the ones of concern:

1. 50% of annual leave must be booked (planned, bot necessarily taken) by September
2. There must be at least two people in the office on all working days
3. The manager has priority over leave during the Christmas break this year as he missed it last year (due to the enforcement of rule number 2 that he introduced).

Due to the slightly chaotic nature of my life outside of work, planning leave a long way ahead is extremely difficult. And although I'm not too concerned about needing 2 people in the office at any time it is obviously more of a concern at Christmas. I don't live very far away from my workplace, we have full remote access and I have said I am prepared to be "On Call" for an emergency but am not physically required in the office. However my manager is adamant that I physically need to be here. Also denying out leave during that period to give himself priority seems an abuse of his position.

Am curious what restrictions they can legally enforce?

Comment: There are also situations in which the employee must take off for religious reasons. For example, a Jewish employee must leave early on Friday during the winter or **cannot** work on the Jewish holidays when he is forbidden to drive a car, write, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The employer can require an employee to take leave and deny leave at particular times. See https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/booking-time-off-